# Reference the result of a method in a method

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-graph-api

I have two methods, the first one gets an access token to access AzureAD, the second is supposed to get user data. I'm able to get it to work when the code is all in the same method, but I'd like to eventually add command line arguments to call different methods, so I'm trying to have the authorization piece seperate and called whenever another method is called. Here's what I have so far.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using PublicClientApplication = Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication;

namespace SharpZure
{
    class SharpZure
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Auth().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static async Task Auth()
        {

            var clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"]).Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string token = null;
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"]).Build();
            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                                   .ExecuteAsync();
            token = result.AccessToken;
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                            async (requestMessage) =>
                            {
                                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                            }));
        }

        static async Task UserData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Display user details");
            var currentUser = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(currentUser.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the problem with this is that in the UserData() method, `graphClient` isn't ever defined, as it's in the Auth() method.

Comment: Why not pass the `GraphServiceClient` as a parameter to your `UserData` method? Alternatively you could add a property to your class that will hold the `GraphServiceClient` instance for all other methods to use it.

Comment: That's what I was figuring, I just didn't know how to code it. Very new to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
namespace SharpZure
{
    class SharpZure
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var graphClient = await Auth();
            UserData(graphClient);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static async Task<GraphServiceClient> Auth()
        {

            var clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"]).Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string token = null;
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"]).Build();
            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                                   .ExecuteAsync();
            token = result.AccessToken;
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                            async (requestMessage) =>
                            {
                                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                            }));
            return graphClient;
        }

        static async Task UserData(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Display user details");
            var currentUser = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(currentUser.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

Simply return the Graph Client from Auth() and pass it to UserData().